# .NET XML Serialization Helper Class

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I Collected the info from one of the previous StackOverflow Q & A that

The following items can be serialized using the `XmlSerializer` class:

- Public read/write properties and fields of public classes
- Classes that implement ICollection or IEnumerable
- XmlElement objects
- XmlNode objects
- DataSet objects

*My Question is how can we develop a XmlSerialize Helper class that takes a Generic Collection as parameter for Xml Serialization.*

Comment: @rengaseshan: I strongly recommend you read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and learn how to use it. Many of your questions are difficult to read because of using HTML.

Comment: Couldn't take it and edited the style, list, typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/CustomXmlSerializer.aspx?msg=3101055

> SUMMARY:CustomXmlSerializer is an
>   alternative to XmlSerializer,
>   supporting both shallow and deep
>   serialization of ArrayLists,
>   Collections, and Dictionaries.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static void Serialize<T>(string filename, T obj)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            xs.Serialize(wr, obj);
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            return (T)xs.Deserialize(rd);
        }
    }
}
```

(it's not specifically for generic collections, it works for any XML-serializable object)

I'm not sure if that's what you were looking for... if not, please detail what you need

Comment: @Will : that's why I said "any **XML-serializable** object"... A dictionary is not XML serializable (unless it implements IXmlSerializable, see this link : http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx)

Comment: @Will: I had same issue, so what I did was I created a new serializable class with two propertie "key" and "Value" in it. Then created List of objects of that class, and serialized it.. this worked for me.. hope it helps you also.

Comment: @Monga: I just use the [KeyedCollection<k,v>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438) now when I need a dictionary that is serializable.